# Is Draw Something available on Blackberry?

Tags: draw-something

Is Draw Something available on Blackberry? I cannot find it, but I am surprised if is is not present...

Comment: Draw Something is not available on Blackberry. As reported by [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), "speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases" is OT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not, and there are currently no plans announced for it to be published on that platform.

And... any speculation on the future of the industry is off-topic here.